# combine two updates based on different condition into a single statement - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to combine two updates based on different condition into a single statement but getting an error and don't understand any other way.

```
UPDATE "Main"
SET status = true
WHERE uid IN (
  SELECT uid
  FROM XYZ
)

UPDATE "Main"
SET status = false
WHERE uid NOT IN (
  SELECT uid
  FROM XYZ
)
```

I tried

```
UPDATE "Main"
SET status = CASE
  WHEN uid IN (
    SELECT uid
    FROM XYZ) THEN true
  ELSE false
END;
```

But getting error as
Unsafe query: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once

Comment: Your issue (error) is not reproducible. Your combine UPDATE works well;) My be this error not from Postgresql.

Comment: The error is not coming from Postgres, it is coming from whatever client you are using.  What is that client? The message is correct the UPDATE will touch all the rows in the table. If that is what you want that then fine, otherwise you will need to add a WHERE clause after CASE section to restrict which row you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the CASE statement to combine the two updates into a single statement and this can be done as follows:

```
UPDATE Main
SET status = CASE
  WHEN uid IN (SELECT uid FROM XYZ) THEN true
  ELSE false
END
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM XYZ);
```

The following statement will only update the status column of rows where the uid column is in the XYZ table

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE` clauses; the records that have a **false** status are those that are not matched :

```
UPDATE Main
SET status = CASE WHEN x.uid is not null then TRUE else FALSE end
FROM Main AS m
LEFT JOIN XYZ x ON x.uid = m.uid
WHERE Main.uid = m.uid; --this line is critical for updating ONLY joined rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression (CTE) to determine the values to set based on the condition and then use a single `UPDATE` statement with a `JOIN`.

```
WITH UpdateValues AS (
  SELECT uid, CASE WHEN uid IN (SELECT uid FROM XYZ) THEN true ELSE false END AS new_status
  FROM "Main"
)
UPDATE "Main" m
SET status = uv.new_status
FROM UpdateValues uv
WHERE m.uid = uv.uid;
```